# NullReferenceException when using foreach loop in Model

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to display data from a database table by using `foreach`, however I am getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_tncl0rkz.dll but was not handled in user code`.
>
> Error at: @foreach (var img in Model)

When I try to access the `View`, the application crashes resulting in mentioned error.

This is my View's `HTML` code *`C#` included as I am programming with visual studio*

```
@model IEnumerable<Common.Image>
....
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.imagePath)</th>
        ....
    </tr>
    @foreach (var img in Model)
    { 
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(imgItem => img.imagePath)</td>
            ....
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This is my `Controller's` `C#` code.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
public ActionResult UsersGallery(string username)
{
    ImagesBL imgBl = new ImagesBL();
    Image img = imgBl.GetImage(username);
    return View(img);
}
```

Comment: No need of foreach, use foreach only list collection. seems like img is just an object. Remove the foreach and try it

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to iterate over an object that is not a collection.  In your controller you are passing a single "Image" and not a collection.  However, your specific error is a null reference exception so it looks like "Model" might be null when it gets to the view.  At some point (either in the controller, or in the view) you will want to check if the object is null before you try accessing any of the properties of the object, otherwise you will get a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

From controller action you are sending single image (`return View(img);`) whereas View is bound to collection of image objects (`@model IEnumerable<Common.Image>`). You need to send collection of images even if it contains single image. Change following statement in action method

```
return View(img);
```

to

```
return View(new List<Image>(){img});
```

Comment: I have tried this, and the error does not appear. The `View` launches, followed by the table headers, but not with the `foreach` statement (which contains the iterative data). 

Do you have any idea what can be the reason?
Thanks again for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You have returned only the object(img type of Image) and not the collections List.

`Use Foreach for the collection only.` If you are not passing the collection to view then you can directly access it in Model.

Your Code: Remove foreach if the img is not an collection.

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.imagePath)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Signature)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Username)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { username = Model.Username }) 
                </td>
            </tr>
```